# Leaflet: How to set the panTo method in a custom control?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm trying to pan and zoom to a part of my map when you click on a thumbnail image using Leaflet's `panTo` method. For some reason it's not working. Can someone help troubleshoot? Here's my code and live demo:

live demo: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/doss1/jbbx87s0/)

relevant code:

```
var jumpKabul = L.Control.extend({
            options: { position: 'bottomleft' },
            onAdd: function(map){
                var container = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'test');
                container.innerHTML = '<div id="map-navigation" class="map-navigation"><a href="#" data-zoom="12" data-position="34.51702396789498,69.11893844604492"><img src="https://placehold.it/150x150"></a></div>';
                return container;
            }
        });

map.addControl(new jumpKabul());

document.getElementById('map-navigation').onclick = function(e) {
var pos = e.target.getAttribute('data-position');
var zoom = e.target.getAttribute('data-zoom');
if (pos && zoom) {
    var loc = pos.split(',');
    var z = parseInt(zoom);
    map.panTo(loc, z, {animation: true});
    return false;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event target isn't what you expect it to be, it's a reference to the `img` not the wrapping `div` element. You could have catched that by logging `e.target` to your console and checking it's contents. If you would use `e.target.parentElement`, you're ok. Next mistake is that you're adding a zoom parameter to the `panTo` function which does not exist:

> panTo(  latlng,  options? )

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-panto

Also you're not using the `L.Control` class to it's full potential. You're still doing the grunt of the work outside of the class, the attaching of the eventhandler and the actual eventhandling etc. Try something like this so you keep all your logic contained within your custom control class (using Leaflet in the snippet but works with Mapbox.js too):

```js
var map = new L.Map('leaflet', {
    'center': [0, 0],
    'zoom': 0,
    'layers': [
        new L.TileLayer('//{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            'attribution': '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, &copy; <a href="http://cartodb.com/attributions">CartoDB</a>'
        })
    ]
});

L.Control.Navigation = L.Control.extend({

    options: {
        position: 'bottomleft'
    },

    onAdd: function (map) {

        var container = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'map-navigation'),
            link = L.DomUtil.create('a', 'map-navigation-link', container),
            img = L.DomUtil.create('img', 'map-navigation-image', link);
            
        link.href = '#';
        // Unsure as why one would need the data attribs
        // Since we could directly use the handler below
        link.dataset.lat = 34.51702396789498;
        link.dataset.lng = 69.11893844604492;
        link.dataset.zoom = 12;
    
        img.src = '//placehold.it/150x150';
        
        L.DomEvent.addListener(link, 'click', function (e) {
            // Using setView because it has zoom
            map.setView([
                link.dataset.lat,
                link.dataset.lng
            ], link.dataset.zoom);
        });

        return container;
    }
});

map.addControl(new L.Control.Navigation());
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

html, body, #leaflet {
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Leaflet 0.7.7</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="leaflet"></div>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="//cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: you saved the day again! Thanks @iH8!